# My live preview for blog entries is not working on my computer, but is working for my account on other computers

Tags: live-preview

When I go to live preview to view my blog entry in draft mode, all I see is a white screen. My co-workers have tested under my account on their computers and it works just fine. Does anyone have any kind of insights for this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you all using the same browser / operating system? Try testing in a recent release of Chrome, Safari, or Internet Explorer.